# Meaning of Local TCP number after double colon when using netstat -a -b -n

Tags: port, netstat

1. Attempting to diagnose port/connection issues and ran into the following output. I know "::" means "any" (replaces consecutive 0's), but what does the 1 mean? It's on chrome, as shown, and a couple UDP connections later.
2. Would the svchost and hasplms having inverse local and foreign addresses potentially cause an issue blocking hasplms?

```
[svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:1947             [::1]:49462            ESTABLISHED
 [hasplms.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:49462            [::1]:1947             ESTABLISHED
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:49671            [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question:

`::1` (long form `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`) is the IPv6 loopback address,
the equivalent of `localhost`.

See [Wikipedia localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).